# Unwanted indentation with `\mintinline` [possible bug]

Tags: minted

I have stumbled upon an indentation problem with `\mintinline` from the `minted`-package in combination with the `breaklines`option.
Consider the following minimal example:

```
%!TEX TS-program = pdflatex
%!TEX TS-options = -shell-escape
\documentclass{scrbook}

\usepackage{minted}
\setmintedinline{breaklines=true}
\begin{document}

A sufficently long text, to make breaking meaningful.  
Lets have some really cool code now \mintinline{text}{cool code}.
Some more code \mintinline{sql}{Test} an how about some Java \mintinline{java}{String a = "hello";}
\end{document}
```

The output (MacTeX 2016, just updated with TeX live Manager):

[image]

Without the `breaklines` option:

[image]

As this extra space in front of the verbatim part in the first image looks *wrong*, I assume this is a bug in `minted`. Any thoughts on this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If I use TeX Live 2015, the output is correct, so the problem seems to belong in `fvextra.sty` (a recent addition). Indeed the package code has
unprotected end-of-lines:

```
   1370 \def\FV@VerbatimPygments#1#2{%
   1371   \edef\FV@PYG@Literal{\expandafter\FV@DetokMacro@StripSpace\detokenize{#1}}%
   1372   \def\FV@BreakBeforePrep@PygmentsHook{%
   1373     \expandafter\FV@BreakBeforePrep@Pygments\expandafter{\FV@PYG@Literal}}
   1374   \def\FV@BreakAfterPrep@PygmentsHook{%
   1375     \expandafter\FV@BreakAfterPrep@Pygments\expandafter{\FV@PYG@Literal}}
   1376   \ifx#2\relax
   1377     \let\FV@PYG#1
   1378   \else
   1379     \let\FV@PYG#2
   1380   \fi
   1381   \ifbool{FV@breakbytoken}%
   1382    {\ifbool{FV@breakbytokenanywhere}%
   1383      {\def\FV@BreakByTokenAnywhereHook{%
   1384         \def\FV@BreakByTokenAnywhereBreak{%
   1385           \let\FV@BreakByTokenAnywhereBreak\FancyVerbBreakByTokenAnywhereBreak}}%
   1386       \def#1##1##2{%
   1387         \FV@BreakByTokenAnywhereBreak
   1388         \leavevmode\hbox{\FV@PYG{##1}{##2}}}}%
   1389      {\def#1##1##2{%
   1390         \leavevmode\hbox{\FV@PYG{##1}{##2}}}}}%
   1391    {\def#1##1##2{%
   1392      \FV@PYG{##1}{\FancyVerbBreakStart##2\FancyVerbBreakStop}}}%
   1393 }
```

(line numbers added for reference).

If I add `%` at the end of lines 1373, 1375, 1377 and 1379, the output is correct:

```
\documentclass{scrbook}

\usepackage{minted}
\setmintedinline{breaklines=true}

\makeatletter
\def\FV@VerbatimPygments#1#2{%
  \edef\FV@PYG@Literal{\expandafter\FV@DetokMacro@StripSpace\detokenize{#1}}%
  \def\FV@BreakBeforePrep@PygmentsHook{%
    \expandafter\FV@BreakBeforePrep@Pygments\expandafter{\FV@PYG@Literal}}% <---
  \def\FV@BreakAfterPrep@PygmentsHook{%
    \expandafter\FV@BreakAfterPrep@Pygments\expandafter{\FV@PYG@Literal}}% <---
  \ifx#2\relax
    \let\FV@PYG#1% <---
  \else
    \let\FV@PYG#2% <---
  \fi
  \ifbool{FV@breakbytoken}%
   {\ifbool{FV@breakbytokenanywhere}%
     {\def\FV@BreakByTokenAnywhereHook{%
        \def\FV@BreakByTokenAnywhereBreak{%
          \let\FV@BreakByTokenAnywhereBreak\FancyVerbBreakByTokenAnywhereBreak}}%
      \def#1##1##2{%
        \FV@BreakByTokenAnywhereBreak
        \leavevmode\hbox{\FV@PYG{##1}{##2}}}}%
     {\def#1##1##2{%
        \leavevmode\hbox{\FV@PYG{##1}{##2}}}}}%
   {\def#1##1##2{%
     \FV@PYG{##1}{\FancyVerbBreakStart##2\FancyVerbBreakStop}}}%
}
\makeatother
\begin{document}

A sufficently long text, to make breaking meaningful.
Lets have some really cool code now \mintinline{text}{cool code}.
Some more code \mintinline{sql}{Test} an how about some Java \mintinline{java}{String a = "hello";}

\end{document}
```

[image]

## Update

With version 1.2.1 of `fvextra` (released 2016/09/02), the issue has been fixed, so the extra code is no longer necessary.

Comment: I've opened an [issue for the bug](https://github.com/gpoore/fvextra/issues/3) and will fix it in the next `fvextra` release.

Comment: @G.Poore Added to my watch list.

Answer (score 1):

This is still present at the time of writing on Ubuntu 16.10 with shipped Latex Packages and can be fixed by updating fvextra.sty to version 1.2.1, as [egreg](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/4427/egreg) said.

fvextra.sty can be found at `/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/fvextra` by default.

The fixed version can be found at Github: [fvextra.sty 1.2.1](https://github.com/gpoore/fvextra/blob/master/fvextra/fvextra.sty)